# check duplicity of a upcoming element in list - python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm trying to check if a string is the same as any string in the list. 
This is what I coded in python:

```
word_split = action_one(element)
while word_split in new_element:
     word_split = action_one(element)
new_element.extend(word_split)
```

This is action one function do:

```
def action_one(element):
    random_position = randint(0, len(element) - 1)
    if random_position == len(element) - 1:
        word_split = [characters[:random_position] + characters[random_position].upper() for characters in element.split()]
    else :
        word_split = [characters[:random_position] + characters[random_position].upper() + characters[random_position + 1 : len(element)] for characters in element.split()]

    return word_split
```

But the output list still have duplicate elements in it. 
Can anyone point out where I did wrong?
Thanks!!

Comment: sample output now is : 'dragon ['dr@gon', 'dragon', 'dragon', 'tiqwfe', 'laiowv', 'dragoN', 'drAgon', 'dragon', 'dRagon']'

Comment: we have no idea what action_one is.

Comment: just added it. Sorry about previous messy format.

Comment: have you tried following your code in a debugger? with a break at a point and step through it?

Comment: There's still some code missing here.

Comment: You can use dictionary to store the existed elements. And then you can lookup from dictionary whether this element has been occurred. Searching in list is ok too, but when you have a lots of elements in a list, your program will become slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There definitely seems to be a typo on this line:

```
while word split in new_element:
```

It shouldn't be more complicated than this:

```
for my_string in my_list 
    if my_string not in my_new_list:
        my_new_list.append(my_string)
```